# MVC Trouble Deleting a record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I get an error when trying to delete a record:

InvalidOperationException - The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.

```
public ActionResult Delete(CustomerModel customer)
        {
            db.Customer.Remove(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
```

**Update**: I checked in the bebugger, customer is completely empty..And therefore the database isn't able to delete that specific record.

Any ideas why?

Comment: try creating an object of the entity, something like this `db = new CustomerEntities();` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *customer* object was not loaded into the DbContext called *db* (I'm assuming it's a DbContext... not entirely clear from your code).

With Entity Framework, the DbContext you are using has to be aware of an object it is acting on.  It looks like you created *customer* in some manner other than by loading it into *db*.

You can add it to the DbContext like this:

```
db.Attach(customer);
```

Then, proceed to remove it and save your changes.

For more details see

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx

Specifically for your case the paragraph *Attaching an existing entity to the context*

**Update** (based on your update)

How did you create *customer* in the first place?  Without that detail, it's just guesswork to understand why it's completely empty.

Comment: Actually this issue is an Entity Framework thing not an MVC thing.  You would see the same error in, say, a Console application using Entity Framework in the same manner.

Comment: I have created Customer using a Model. The CustomerModel class simply has name, id, address etc... I can create a user using db.Customer.Add(customer); etc but this Delete method isn't working.

Comment: Presumably the Delete is happening during a different HTTP request than the original Add.  That means the DbContext doesn't know about it, so can't delete it.  Make sure the ID is populated in the object you want to delete, than just add the line of code suggested in my answer.